# Y axis values of a Google chart with two Y axis

Tags: google-visualization, graph-visualization

I have tried a lot to get a Google chart look like this,

[image]

with this code,

```
new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('onlineUsers_chart')).
            draw(dataTable, {
                isStacked: true,
                vAxes: {
                    0: { 'minValue': 3050 },
                    1: { 'minValue': 2 }
                },
                series: {
                    0: { targetAxisIndex: 0, type: "line" },
                    1: { targetAxisIndex: 1 },
                    2: { targetAxisIndex: 1 },
                    3: { targetAxisIndex: 1 }
                },
                options: {
                    legend: {
                        position: 'bottom'
                    },
                    colors: ['#3366CC', '#DC3912', '#A6A6A6', '#3366CC'],
                    pointSize: 3,
                    chartArea: {
                        left: 60,
                        top: 20,
                        bottom: 60,
                        width: "100%",
                        height: "1000px"
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

This is what I get,

[image]

I can't figure out a way to make the minimum value of first Y axis to 3050. 
And the color options and legend place options are not working properly. Should I use a different chart type instead ColumnChart?

Comment: minValue doesn't do what you think it does.  It means the chart will show at least that min value, but it can show more.  What you want is to use the viewWindow.min option.  E.g. vAxes: 1: { viewWindow: { min: 2 } }

Comment: Thanks @dlaliberte . Using viewWindow.min option I was able to set the Y axis values as I wanted.
However the Legend position and bar colors are still not appearing properly. I wonder ColumnChart type is the best for this chart.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve the issues.

Y axis values are set using the viewWindow.min option
All the Options are working when it is stated without a 'Options' attribute. 
And yes I changed the chart type to ComboChart.

Here's the code

```
new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('onlineUsers_chart')).
        draw(dataTable, {
            isStacked: true,
            vAxes: {
                0: { viewWindow: { min: 3050 } },
                1: { viewWindow: { min: -60 }}
            },
            series: {
                0: { targetAxisIndex: 0, type: "line" },
                1: { targetAxisIndex: 1, type: "bars" },
                2: { targetAxisIndex: 1, type: "bars" },
                3: { targetAxisIndex: 1, type: "bars" }
            },
           // options: {
                legend: {
                    position: 'bottom'
                },
                colors: ['#3366CC', '#DC3912', '#A6A6A6', '#3366CC'],
                pointSize: 3,
                chartArea: {
                    left: 60,
                    top: 20,
                    bottom: 60,
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "1000px"
                }
            //}
        }
    );
```